# How to get localstorage to alert the prompted username variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code. I'm trying to alert the myname variable value after saving it in `localStorage`, but instead of getting the variable's saved value, I only get the variable name in the alert.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
  localStorage.setItem('username', 'myname');
  localStorage.getItem('username');
  alert('username');
});
```

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ - you are alerting a static _text_. And you call getItem without doing anything with the result.

Comment: Please check the answers below, update your code that as well. don't put strings everywhere when you want to use vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Your final code would be:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
  localStorage.setItem('username', myname);
  var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
  alert(username);
});
```

**Why:**

Surely **username** is not defined anywhere, it is just a string and you are putting a alert on it.

Also you are not setting your **prompt** value in setItem() either.

Either store your getItem value in a variable

```
var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
```

Or alert this one

```
localStorage.getItem('username');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `alert(localStorage.getItem('username'))`

Answer (score 2):

Change  `alert('username')` to `alert(localStorage.getItem('username'))`

Answer (score 1):

You put the `localStorage.getItem`-result into a variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
    localStorage.setItem('username', 'myname');
    var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    alert(username);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

getItem() returns a value, you get set it into a variable

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
    localStorage.setItem('username', myname);
    var user = localStorage.getItem('username');
    alert(user);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you only get the variable name inside the alert is that you are just giving a string to the setItem that is the same as your variable name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
    localStorage.setItem('username', myname);
    var item = localStorage.getItem('username');
    alert(item);
    });
```

The way you can fix this is just changing the `'myname'` into a the variable `myname`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to alert a variable i.e. not defined.

Variable `username`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myname = prompt("What is your name, friend?");
  localStorage.setItem('username', 'myname');
  var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
  alert('username');
});
```

Hope this will help you.